# Hiding data from a DefaultTableModel to the GUI

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

I have a `DefaultTableModel` that have 4 columns, one of the columns is a ID and I don't want to show it on the view of the table but I need to keep track of the ID when the user clicks on a row.

```
private void añadeFilas(boolean europa, boolean caribe) {
    Object[] nuevaFila = new Object[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < agencia.getCruceros().size(); i++) {
        String zona = agencia.getCruceros().get(i).getZona();
        if ((europa && zona.equals("Europa")) || (caribe && zona.equals("Caribe"))) {
            nuevaFila[0] = agencia.getCruceros().get(i).getZona();
            nuevaFila[1] = agencia.getCruceros().get(i).getDenominacion();
            nuevaFila[2] = agencia.getCruceros().get(i).getPuertoSalida();
            nuevaFila[3] = agencia.getCruceros().get(i).getCodigo();

            modeloTabla.addRow(nuevaFila);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I fill the model and the column I want to hide is: `nuevaFila[3]`

I have tried this way:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (tableCruceros.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                    btSeleccion.setEnabled(true);
                    int fila = tableCruceros.getSelectedRow();
                    String cod = (String) ((Vector) modeloTabla.getDataVector().elementAt(fila)).elementAt(3);
                    crucero = agencia.findByCod(cod);
                    agencia.leerFicheroBarcos(crucero.getCodigoBarco());
                }
                mostrarVentanaCrucero();
            }
        });
```

But it throws me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at igu.VentanaPrincipal$5.actionPerformed(VentanaPrincipal.java:238)
```

238 is ->                       String cod = (String) ((Vector) modeloTabla.getDataVector().elementAt(fila)).elementAt(3);

PD. sorry if there is any grammar or spelling mistake

Comment: Create the model, apply it to the table, get the TableColumnModel and remove the ID column form it OR create a POJO which represents your data, write a TableModel which is capable using it and simply don't display the ID

Comment: I echo what @MadProgrammer states. If you go the latter route, you will likely be using instances of your POJO as rows in your model, and if so, you will likely want your model class to extend AbstractTableModel and not DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MadProgrammer and @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, finally I tried removing the column.

The code i have used:

```
TableColumn columna = tableCruceros.getColumn("Codigo");
tableCruceros.removeColumn(columna);
```

and it seems to work :)